# ActiveRecord adding DISTINCT on column that isn't specified by my code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the snippet below on one of my `Client` model:

```
has_many :roles
has_many :cases, :through => :roles
```

In the database, there are three (3) roles:

```
id | role | case_id | client_id
1  |   1  |   50    |    60
2  |   2  |   50    |    60
3  |   3  |   50    |    60
```

The records are almost identical, however, the role column is different in each row.

The ActiveRecord query `Client.includes(:cases).where(cases: { id: 1459 })` produces the query below which is adding a `DISTINCT` causing it to only get one row from the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `clients`.`id`) FROM `clients` LEFT OUTER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` AND `roles`.`deleted_at` IS NULL LEFT OUTER JOIN `cases` ON `cases`.`id` = `roles`.`case_id` AND `cases`.`deleted_at` IS NULL WHERE `clients`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `cases`.`id` = 1459
```

How can I communicate to ActiveRecord not to include that `DISTINCT clients.id` snippet?

Comment: Which id is 1459 referencing?

Comment: cases.id as can be seen in both the AR query and MySQL query.

Comment: OH Try just the where  "Client.where(cases: { id: 1459 })"

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have default scopes at play here? Can you post those?

Comment: You could try Client.unscoped.includes(:cases).where(cases: { id: 1459 }) Then figure out how to manage the conflict.

Comment: Same thing without unscoped.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT` is clearly not what you're asking for, and that in combination with the sequence of `deleted_at IS NULL` calls makes me feel there's definitely some scoping at play. What gems might be affecting this? `deleted_at` might be a couple different gems, yeah?

Comment: ...but where would a scope force a `.count()` call...?

Comment: deleted_at is from the paranoia gem.  All that does is handle soft-deleting.  The reason it's COUNT is because I'm caliing `.size` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The `include` method will generate a distinct count query on a `has_many` relation (the foreign key). Use `Client.joins(:cases).where(cases: { id: 1459 })` to avoid adding DISTINCT to your query.

Your query should now be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `clients` INNER JOIN `roles`
ON `roles`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` AND
`roles`.`deleted_at` IS NULL LEFT OUTER JOIN
`cases` ON `cases`.`id` = `roles`.`case_id`
AND `cases`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
WHERE `clients`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND `cases`.`id` = 1459
```

Comment: Check comment on above answer.